# Efficient solution for a special assignment problem

Tags: algorithm, variable-assignment

Given:

-A set of items that each have costs for being placed into a given container type.

-A set of container types that each have a number of available containers.

Example:

Amount*Container-Type : 5 * A, 3 * B, 2 * C

Items(Costs) :

3 * X (A=2, B=3, C=1)

2 * Y (A=5, B=2, C=2)

1 * Z (A=3, B=3, C=1)

Problem:

Find the best placement of the items into the containers so that the costs are minimal. For simplicity, only place an item into a single type of container.

I tried the hungarian method to solve the problem, but with a runtime of O(n³), it's quite prohibitive for large problems (e.g., 100000 items).

My current solution is a greedy approach, that just orders the item-container combinations by costs (asc) and assigns the first container with a sufficient amount left in O(n log n).

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5):

This problem is a variant of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), start at the Wikipedia page and read on from there.

The greedy algorithm is known to be a reasonably good appoximation, so you are probably good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Nahively I would go for a genetic aproach, given that genomes are easy to generate, mutate and cross-breed. but there may be an optimal non-combinatory solution.

Comment: Well, the poster wasn't specific in the nature of the answer he wanted, granted, but I imagine he'd want something provably minimal, which he should specify.  Not sure this really fits the bill.

Comment: Agreed, but some problems (and it seems this one is NOT the case) are well known to be hard to solve using just mathematics, and in those cases a genetic algorithm surely classifies as simple.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, you only need some maths:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) as a [linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) and solving it using the [simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)?

Comment: The trouble with this is he's in the integer domain, which turns it into Integer Linear Programming which can't use the simplex algorithm. Otherwise it's the right solution.